Черный экран при запуске приложения с flet через PyCharm
Делал разные проекты в PyCharm с библиотекой Flet. Всё работало нормально, окно с интерфейсом выводилось.
Сейчас создал новый проект, написал код, а он выводит окно, но там всё черное.
При этом старые проекты открываются нормально, этот же код в VC Code открывается без проблем + в WEB-режиме всё ок.
Попробовал в старом проекте создать новый файл и вставить код - все успешно отработало.
С чем это может быть связано?
import flet as ft
from time import sleep
import math


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Программа для расчета характеристик малоотражающего покрытия"
    page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.scroll = 'always'
    page.theme_mode = 'light'

def close(e):
    page.window_close()

btn_disp = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Расчет дисперсии", width=300, height=50)

btn_kof = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Расчет R и T-коэффициентов", width=300, height=50)

btn_exit = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Выход", width=300, height=50, on_click=close)


general_cont_5 = ft.Container(
    padding=5,
    border_radius=20,
    bgcolor='yellow',
    content=ft.Row(
        [
            btn_disp,
            btn_kof,
            btn_exit
        ]
    )
)


panel_4 = ft.Column(
    [
        general_cont_5
    ]
)

page.add(panel_4)


ft.app(target=main)



